# Display Charts on VisualForce Page?

Tags: force.com

How to generate Column Chart in Visualforce pages and I have a requirement that on click of color column of chart , i have to perform some task. How can i perform that also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a JavaScript based solution with Google Charts.

- Create a [Google Column Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).
- From your page, get the data from a Salesforce.  Here are some possibilities.

  1. Create an Apex controller and call to it from your page. Look at using a @RemoteAction to get the data. You may want to use the Analytics API in Apex to get the data.
  2. Use the Analytics API via REST in JavaScript and don’t use an Apex Controller at all.
  3. Use Remote Objects and don’t use an Apex Controller at all.

- Configure your chart to handle the event.  See [Handling Events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events) and [Column Chart Events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Events).

Here is a simple example from the Google Column Chart docs. You would need to replace the static sample data with data retrieved dynamically and also add in the event handling.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how can I add the report into this code so that specific value can be shown? Thanks