# How to show Chart in Visualforce page which has renderas = pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf, charts, renderas

I have VF page with `renderAs = PDF`.

I want to display a chart on that PDF?

I have tried https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_example.htm and [Display Charts on VisualForce Page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54847/display-charts-on-visualforce-page)

but these only works on HTML, not in `renderAs = PDF`.

Thanks in advance.